# Filter Array of Array for values inside nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I'm trying to get my head around this i have an array with nested arrays like so

```
var array = [
  [12, 43801309, "21.10.2018 00:00:00", 0.00089, 0.00055, 0.0004],
  [13, 43801308, "22.10.2018 00:00:00", 0.00089, 0.00055, 0.0004],
  [34, 43801307, "23.10.2018 00:00:00", 0.00089, 0.00055, 0.0004],
  [234, 43801308, "24.10.2018 00:00:00", 0.00089, 0.00055, 0.0004]
]
```

i would like to filter the [index = 1] of those nested arrays for certain values like 43801309
if it'll be just single values inside that array

```
array.filter(function(val) { 
    return val === lookupVal;
});
```

would just work fine, but if i try

```
array.filter(function(arr) {
    return arr.filter(function(val) {
        return val === lookupVal;
    });
});
```

it does not work

Comment: `array.filter(val => val[1] === lookupVal);`?.. Is the array lookup value always the second element of the inner array?

Comment: yes always the second value

Comment: `arr.filter` returns an array, which is always `true` in JavaScript. So it will be kept in the initial (outer) array. This is true even for empty ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the [index] is always the second element of the array, you can simply check whether the value at index 1 is the desired index.

```js
var array = [
  [12, 43801309, "21.10.2018 00:00:00", 0.00089, 0.00055, 0.0004],
  [13, 43801308, "22.10.2018 00:00:00", 0.00089, 0.00055, 0.0004],
  [34, 43801307, "23.10.2018 00:00:00", 0.00089, 0.00055, 0.0004],
  [234, 43801308, "24.10.2018 00:00:00", 0.00089, 0.00055, 0.0004]
];

var targetIndex = 43801308;

var filtered = array.filter(val => val[1] === targetIndex);

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can customize your filter condition

`if(c.indexOf(43801308) > -1` if no check index

`if(c[1] == 43801308)`  if check index 1

```
let data = [
  [12, 43801309, "21.10.2018 00:00:00", 0.00089, 0.00055, 0.0004],
  [13, 43801308, "22.10.2018 00:00:00", 0.00089, 0.00055, 0.0004],
  [34, 43801307, "23.10.2018 00:00:00", 0.00089, 0.00055, 0.0004],
  [234, 43801308, "24.10.2018 00:00:00", 0.00089, 0.00055, 0.0004]
];

let result = data.filter(c=> { if(c.indexOf(43801308) > -1) return c;});
console.log(result);
```

```js
let data = [
  [12, 43801309, "21.10.2018 00:00:00", 0.00089, 0.00055, 0.0004],
  [13, 43801308, "22.10.2018 00:00:00", 0.00089, 0.00055, 0.0004],
  [34, 43801307, "23.10.2018 00:00:00", 0.00089, 0.00055, 0.0004],
  [234, 43801308, "24.10.2018 00:00:00", 0.00089, 0.00055, 0.0004]
];

let result = data.filter(c=> { if(c.indexOf(43801308) > -1) return c;});

//if only need index 1
result = data.filter(c=> { if(c[1] == 43801308) return c;});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array.filter(function(arr) {
    return arr[1] === value;
}
```

This should solve your problem. You don't seem to want to filter the nested array, but rather choose the ones where a value is included.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to filter twice. What you really want to achieve is filter rows that match a certain condition, in your case, the condition is `row[1] === lookupVal`.

```js
const array = [
  [12, 43801309, "21.10.2018 00:00:00", 0.00089, 0.00055, 0.0004],
  [13, 43801308, "22.10.2018 00:00:00", 0.00089, 0.00055, 0.0004],
  [34, 43801307, "23.10.2018 00:00:00", 0.00089, 0.00055, 0.0004],
  [234, 43801308, "24.10.2018 00:00:00", 0.00089, 0.00055, 0.0004]
];

const lookupVal = 43801308;
const filterRows = array.filter(row => row[1] === lookupVal);

console.log(filterRows);
```